# c# Referencing a class instance from a list using a value of a property as the index

Tags: c#, list

How do I construct the Lst class so I can reference specific instances by a property of the class?  If it isn't possible in a List is it possible in an Lst[] array?  Does creating/using/referencing a list in this pattern have a name?

The error I get is `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'`
on the two l["..List"] inside the Console.WriteLine()

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    public class Lst {
        public string Name;
        public Lst(string Name) { this.Name = Name; }
        public Lst this[string Name] { get { return this[Name]; } }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Lst> l = new List<Lst>();
            l.Add(new Lst("1stList"));
            Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", l["1stList"].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", l["2ndList"].Name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you're receiving is because you're trying to use the index on the C# `List<T>`, not your `Lst` class. For `List<T>`, it indexes by `int` position.

Comment: Your `Lst` isn't a list of anything. It's not even a collection. It's a class with a single property (`Name`). Your indexer is meaningless (in fact it's self-referential and will blow up your stack). The indexer you're actually calling belongs to `List<T>`.

Comment: Try to use `Dictionary<string,Lst>` instead of `List<Lst>`, this however has small overhead (key value is doubled).

Comment: I think you need a `Dictionary` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you are looking for  a Dictionary  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2344/an-overview-of-c-sharp-collections/12061/dictionarytkey-tvalue#t=20161207163345473274

Comment: @MaksimSimkin.  Okay I see that.  I'll attempt to rewrite this a a dictionary.  I'm wondering if you would also and post it here so I can check it as a solution.

Comment: Is there a name for the syntax of the 'public object this[]' property that uses square brackets instead of ()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KUDOs to Weyland Yutani.**

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

> **Expression Body Definitions**
>
> It is common to have indexers that simply return immediately with the
> result of an expression. There is a syntax shortcut for defining these
> indexers using =>: C#
>
> ```
> public Customer this[long id] => store.LookupCustomer(id);
> ```
>
> The indexer must be read only, and you do not use the get accessor
> keyword.
>
> **Indexers Overview**
>
> • Indexers enable objects to be indexed in a similar manner to arrays.
>
> • A **get** accessor returns a value. A **set** accessor assigns a value.
>
> • The **this** keyword is used to define the indexers.
>
> • The value keyword is used to define the value being assigned by the
> set  indexer.
>
> • **Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value**; it is up
> to you how to define the specific look-up mechanism.
>
> • Indexers can be overloaded.
>
> • Indexers can have more than one formal parameter, for example, when
> accessing a two-dimensional array.

.

I would love to find the language grow to where any property can be used as a indexer without have to write my own indexer function.  But until then we have Linq.

The interesting parts being lines 47 & 10.
(updated: using a better image)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How do I construct the Lst class so I can reference specific instances
>   by a property of the class?

You can use LINQ to obtain an item from the list that matches a condition. For example to obtain items with specific names:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Lst> l = new List<Lst>();
        l.Add(new Lst("1stList"));
        Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", l.First(item => item.Name == "1stList").Name);
        Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", l.First(item => item.Name == "2ndList").Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Lst 
{
    public string Name;
    public Lst(string Name) { this.Name = Name; }
}
```

Comment: @Is there a name for the syntax of the 'public object this[]' property that uses square brackets instead of ()?

Comment: It is an expression body AND being used in a getter/setter?